# How to scale a background image to fit the full width of the screen while maintaining aspect ratio? Height is cut off when I use "cover"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

**OBJECTIVE**

This is my website https://saddhustore.com.br/moda/. I want the main image at the top to scale down to fit 1366x768 screens just as it does in my 1920x1080, displaying **all of it, without distorting the aspect ratio** at all.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I am using Elementor in WordPress. In the "**Custom CSS**" part I have tried to add the following code:

```
selector {
    background-size: cover; OR background-size: contain; OR background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

When using cover, I have tried adding `background-attachment: fixed` and `height: 100%` to no avail.

**RESULTS AFTER APPLYING MAGGI'S SUGGESTION**

Notice the bottommost part gets cut off

[image]

For some reason it looks perfect within Elementor

Comment: Please show us relevant CSS and HTML.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for replying. What do you mean? I am using WordPress and Elementor. I have shared all of my CSS and never touched any HTML

Comment: Unless the container has exactly the same aspect ratio as the image, it will never fit perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following code in css
(note: set height of selector to manual like this):

```css
selector {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    height: 50vh   /*manual add*/;
    width:100vw;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! It works almost perfectly! In Elementor it is 100% correct but, unfortunately, in both Chrome and Firefox the bottommost  part gets cut off. I've updated the website and included a screenshot of how it looks now in my original post for you to see. Setting overflow to visible didn't seem to work

Comment: add manual height to selector.

Comment: Please excuse me but how do I do that?

Comment: This is what I did https://pasteboard.co/Z59xxg0APWCW.png

Comment: change height to 60 to 80 vh.

Comment: here example: https://codepen.io/yash_ramoliya123/pen/oNGWVzj